# Vector space spanning proof.

Tags: vector-spaces

**Question:**

Consider in a real vector space $V$ the subspace $U$ spanned by the set $\{u_1, u_2, . . . , u_k\}$.
Prove that $U\subseteq \tilde{U}$ for any subspace $\tilde{U}\subseteq V$ which contains all $k$ vectors $u_1, u_2, . . . , u_k$.

**My thoughts and attempt.**

Non-existent attempt so far as I'm very stuck. What I know are the definitions of a vector space, subspace and the spanning set.

Any help and guidance is very appreciated thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you are going to have to show set containment, so when you begin you want to think about how to show that for every $v \in U$ one has $v \in \tilde{U}$. Now, we can unpack $v$ because we know that we can fix $c_i \in \mathbb{F}$ so that
$$v = c_1 u_1 + c_2u_2 + \cdots + c_k u_k$$
from the definition of $U$. We have to show that $v \in \tilde{U}$, so it suffices to show that 
$$c_1 u_1 + c_2u_2 + \cdots + c_k u_k \in \tilde{U}.$$
Now, we know that $\{u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_k\} \subseteq \tilde{U}$, and we also know that $\tilde{U}$ is a subspace of $V$, which implies that $\tilde{U}$ contains linear combinations of its elements. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: No sorry I think I'm getting more of a sense as to what you're getting at but I fear I cannot do the whole solution myself.

Comment: Well, since $v$ _is_ a linear combination of $\{ u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_k \}$, we can conclude that $v \in \tilde{U}$. Since $v \in U$ was arbitrary, this holds for every $v \in U$; hence, $U \subseteq \tilde{U}$.